# Google Maps Flash API markers raising to top on mouseover- how to disable?

Tags: flash, maps

In Google Maps flash API, I have some Markers added to the map and I noticed that when I mouseover a marker it rises to the front- I want to  disable this on certain markers because they don't need to rise to the top- i want them to maintain their layer structure.

In the javascript version there seems to be a marker property called 'raiseondrag' but this doesnt' exist in the flash version.

any ideas?
thanks

andy